# ActiveRecord - get the last 20 records of a where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an ActiveRecord query:

```
@results = Instrument.where("id < ?", this_id).limit(20)
```

This returns the first 20 records that match the criteria. I am trying to find a method of efficiently getting the last 20 records of the query.

To be more specific, if I have 100 records total with id 1 through 100 and I specify

```
this_id = 51
@results = Instrument.where("id < ?", this_id).limit(20)
```

I get records 1 thru 20, whereas I want to get records 31 to 50. Is there an efficient way to do this? I am trying to avoid reading the entire database up to the search criteria just to take the last 20.

By the way, this SQL does exactly what I am looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM instruments WHERE id < 151000 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 ) sub ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: What database are you using You could do a subquery along the lines of `Instrument.where(id: Instrument.where("id < ?", this_id).limit(50)).limit(20)` but there are probably a lot more elegant solutions.

Comment: @max: I'm running on postgresql. Not sure your suggestion works - it will get the first 50 records rather than the last - I already tried limit().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the SQL query in the update of your question, you can use `from` to pass a subquery and build something like that:

```
Instrument
  .from(Instrument.where('id < ?', 151_000).order(id: :desc).limit(10),
        :instruments)
  .order(:id)
```

Comment: Nice. If you use a table alias `.from(..., :instruments)` you can get rid of `.select(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```rb
@results = Instrument.where("id < ?", this_id).last(20)
```

Comment: My understanding is that this will read in all records up to id, then take the last 20. Would be ok if the database is small, but when it gets into the m's I don't want to be reading in 5m records just to get 20 of em.